# Plotting a sequence of strings using sprintf in R

Tags: r, printf

I want to start using sprintf to plot a series of two strings in R for a title of a figure. Can anyone show me how to do it correctly? The values from HS and score should be plotted as characters behind the terms in quotes.

```
title = sprintf ("HS %s", as.character(HS), "Score %s", as.character(score))
```

Comment: In your original code you have an extra `)`.

I am not sure from your explanation, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

`title = sprintf ("HS %s Score %s", as.character(HS), as.character(score))`

Maybe you can clarify your question by adding expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sprintf`, we can multiple arguments as the usage is

> sprintf(fmt, ...)

That implies, there would be a single `fmt` and any number of inputs

```
 sprintf("%HS %s Score %s", as.character(HS), as.character(score))
```